# Callback testing with promise resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose

I m trying to develop and test a new application and I m having some troubles, concerning callback behaviour for unit testing.

Here's the code that I need to test :

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
 MongooseModel.populate(toPopulate, options, (err, demands) => {
        if (!err) {
          for (let item of demands) {
            list.push(invert(item));
          }
          resolve(list);
        } else {
          reject({
            errorCode: ErrorList.DER06,
            detail: err
          });
        }
      });
});
```

The fact is that I don't know at all how to mock the Mongoose populate with the callback call.

Does any body knows how I can unit test the callback behaviour here ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: *"Strange Promise behaviour with babeljs"* doesn't seem to relate to the question *"how I can unit test the callback behaviour here"*...? Your title should reflect your question.

Comment: How is this different from any other unit testing/mocking you do?

Comment: I dont know how to mock the Mongoose.populate callback (third parameter) value in that case :-/

Comment: You don't mock that callback. You should test that the callback does what you expect. You get to it by mocking MongooseModel.populate.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but how do I simulate the callback behaviour that needs external (Promise resolution) functions inside of it ? I m not in the same context